# "for var = 1, 2" in Lua

Tags: for-loop, lua

What does this kind of loop do in Lua?

```
for count = 1, 2 do
    -- do stuff
end
```

The variable `count` isn't used in the body of the loop.

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html

Comment: @HenriMenke Yeah, dumb question from me, sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It executes the body of the loop twice.

There's no need to refer to `count` inside the loop unless you need to know its current value.

```
for count = 1,5 do
    print("Hello")
end
```

prints

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case `count` is "dummy variable" - "dummy" in that a variable is used fulfill a certain construct *even though the variable is not used*. (Another common name for such a usage is `_`, although `count` arguably adds a little more semantic intent.)

Such a dummy variable is used because [LUA loops *require* a variable / assignment in the grammar construct](https://www.lua.org/pil/4.3.4.html). However, there is no requirement that the variable is used - hence a "dummy".

> .. A **numeric for [loop]** has the following syntax:
>
> ```
> for var=exp1,exp2,exp3 do
>   something
> end
> ```
>
> *That loop will execute something for each value of var from exp1 to exp2*, using exp3 as the step to increment var. This third expression [exp3] is optional; when absent, Lua assumes one [1] as the step value.